# What is the recommended pressure for refueling an Airbus A380?

Tags: airbus-a380, refueling

What is the recommended pressure on the hose that refuels an Airbus A380 when fueling this aircraft? How many litres per minute does it pump into the tanks. Can it safely be increased to reduce fueling time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A380 [airport planning manual](https://www.airbus.com/aircraft/support-services/airport-operations-and-technical-data/aircraft-characteristics.html) states (emphasis mine):

> Refuel pressure:
>   - **Maximum** pressure: 50 psi (3.45 bar).

Can it be safely increased? Doubtful. Any increase [may damage](https://www.ntsb.gov/about/employment/_layouts/ntsb.aviation/brief2.aspx?ev_id=20010918X01956&ntsbno=DEN01FA157&akey=1) internal aircraft systems, and not only that, the operators will need to ask the airports to install new refueling systems.

[Generally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_fuel#Underwing):

> For pressure refueling, a high-pressure hose is attached and fuel is pumped in at 275 kilopascals (40 psi) and a maximum of 310 kilopascals (45 psi) for most commercial aircraft. Pressure for military aircraft, especially fighters, ranges up to 415 kilopascals (60 psi).

As for the rate, from the graphic and the text:

> [image]
>
> 242 700 l (64 115 US gal) at 40 psig.

242,700 l take 36 minutes, or ~6,700 l/min.

Comment: Also note that refueling is a significantly shorter process than cleaning and restocking catering. Speeding up the fueling process won't buy anything in regards to turn around time.